# Not able to add <br> to value in web.config

Tags: web-config

I want to display some message and I want to store the value in `web.config`

```
<add key="Msg" value="Incompatible Format! <br> Please select Image file"></add>
```

here i get error in `<br>` and its considering the text after that as a different value

I tried using escape sequence  `/<br/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found from asp.net [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1319776.aspx?how%20to%20add%20line%20break%20in%20the%20web%20config%20file%20) that i need to use

```
&lt;br&gt;
```

which is equivalent to `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to html encode the value

```
Incompatible Format! &lt;br&gt; Please select Image file
```

Comment: Thanks @Oscar :) this works
I was trying with escape sequence which didnt work!

Comment: @vignesh Yopur're welcome. Remember, you need to html encode all html tags in text when they are in an xml document.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *escape* such characters in XML/HTML. See [here](http://xmmssc-www.star.le.ac.uk/SAS/xmmsas_20070308_1802/doc/param/node24.html) for more details.

For XML I would normally expect to be able to enclose the entire string in a [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) section. However it appears (from the comments below) that this isn't an option for `web.config`

Comment: You can't use a cdata section for this, is not allowed in the web.config schema for appSettings

Comment: Is it not a standard XML document ?

Comment: It is an xml document, but it must follow a predefined schema, you just can't place a cdata section wherever you want.. Also, the support classes to handle configuration won't search for a value inside a cdata, it must be inside the "value" attribute.

Comment: It seems to me (and I'm not familiar with what actually works in a web.config doc, so I'm not disagreeing on that point) that either CDATA is allowed, since it's an XML doc, or it isn't, in which case web.config *isn't* an XML doc. Is that fair ?

Comment: CDATA s allowed, but it is useless, as it will be ignored by the supporting classes.